# Django-filter pagination duplicates

Tags: django

I'm trying to filter a model and paginate it, but for some reason, I get duplicates in my query. I try to filter the following model by brand:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    brand_choices = [
        ('Apple', 'Apple'),
        ('Samsung', 'Samsung'),
        ('Honor', 'Honor'),
    ]

    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=brand_choices, blank=False, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], blank=False, null=True)
```

Here is my current model state:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | brand   | price |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | Apple   |     1 |
|  2 | Apple   |     2 |
|  3 | Apple   |     3 |
|  4 | Apple   |     4 |
|  5 | Apple   |     5 |
|  6 | Samsung |     6 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

And everything is ok when I try to get all the objects, it returns this query:

```
<QuerySet [<Post: Post object (6)>, <Post: Post object (5)>, <Post: Post object (4)>, <Post: Post object (3)>, <Post: Post object (2)>, <Post: Post object (1)>]>
```

And it renders in template like this:

```
Samsung 6
Apple 5
Apple 4
Apple 3
Apple 2
Apple 1
```

But when I filter model by brand=Apple it returns almost the same queryset:

```
<QuerySet [<Post: Post object (6)>, <Post: Post object (5)>, <Post: Post object (4)>, <Post: Post object (3)>, <Post: Post object (2)>, <Post: Post object (1)>]>
```

The only difference is that Post object 6 and Post object 5 are the same objects and it renders whole query in template like this:

```
Apple 5
Apple 4
Apple 4
Apple 3
Apple 2
Apple 1
```

Here is my view:

```
def index(request):
    
    myposts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    myfilter = PostFilter(request.GET, queryset=myposts)
    posts = myfilter.qs

    paginator = Paginator(posts, 2)
    page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_num)
    except EmptyPage:
        page = paginator.page(1)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page = paginator.page(1)

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': page, 'myfilter': myfilter})
```

And here is my filter if that makes sense:

```
class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    price_gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='price', lookup_expr='gte')
    price_lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='price', lookup_expr='lte')

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['brand']
```

Also when I filter by brand=Apple and I go from page 1:

```
Apple 5
Apple 4
```

On the page 2 I see this:

```
Apple 4
Apple 3
```

And when I go back to the page 1 I see this:

```
Samsung 6
Apple 5
```

I don't know what to do. And I really hope that someone helps me

Edit:
Here is my template part with links to other pages:

```
{% if posts.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">Pre</a>
{% endif %}
{% if posts.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It's not your filters problem or anything. You are just losing the get parameters when you are changing the pages. Please show your template on how you render the anchors for the next page.

Comment: Can you please share the template part where you go to the next/previous page?

Comment: I updated my question, take a look please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You render your page urls as `"?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}"`. The problem is this does not keep the current get parameters of your filter and hence your filter does not work.

One great [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html) I had followed for this issue was from the blog [Simple is Better than Complex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/) (Great blog for learning Django). But I later found somewhat of an even simpler [solution](https://gist.github.com/benbacardi/d6cd0fb8c85e1547c3c60f95f5b2d5e1) by [Ben Cardy](https://gist.github.com/benbacardi) in the same posts comments.

Both ways involve making a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/). In the answer I would show how to use the solution in the second link.

Firstly you need to add a `templatetags` directory with an `__init__.py` file inside it to your app. In this directory we would add our custom template tags. Let's say we will write them in a file `my_tags.py`. The directory structure would look something like:

```
yourapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        my_tags.py
    views.py
```

In `my_tags.py` we will add the following code:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def relative_url(context, **kwargs):
    query = context['request'].GET.copy()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        query[k] = v
    return query.urlencode()
```

Basically we are making a template tag `relative_url` which takes the context from the template and uses the get parameters from the request and adds the arguments you provide to them. After which it simply returns a url encoded version of them.

Now in your template you will first load these tags at the start of your file and then use them for your page links:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{% if posts.has_previous %}
    <a href="?{% relative_url page=posts.previous_page_number %}">Pre</a>
{% endif %}
{% if posts.has_next %}
    <a href="?{% relative_url page=posts.next_page_number %}">Next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/page%3D2
and url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/page=2

Comment: Oh. I fixed it, I added '?' to <a href="?{% relative_url page=posts.next_page_number %}">Next</a>. And now it works

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I very appreciate your help! Thanks for your brilliant solution!